# after running invoke-sqlcmd why is the fileSystem provider required to access UNC Server paths

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

after reading the following link I was able to resolve my own issue - but does anyone know why the FileSystem Provider is required here after using invoke-sqlcmd 
ie. why does the following fail

```
$Doc_Folder = "\\Server.fqdn.com\c$\DocFiles" 
$DataSet = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlQuery -ServerInstance $instanceName -username $SQLCreds.UserName -Password $pswd 
Get-ChildItem $Doc_Folder -recurse
```

and why does the following work

```
$Doc_Folder = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\Server.fqdn.com\c$\DocFiles" 
$DataSet = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlQuery -ServerInstance $instanceName -username $SQLCreds.UserName -Password $pswd 
Get-ChildItem $Doc_Folder -recurse
```

This is the link where I found the solution to adding the file system provider *Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem:::* 
[powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-get-childitem-cannot-call-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102234/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-get-childitem-cannot-call-method-the-provider-does-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server modules that shipped with SQLServer prior to August of 2016 changed the directory to the SQLSERVER: drive.

To get around this, you should install the SQLServer module (from PSGallery) or, if you need to use the older stuff (for compatibility reasons), you can do this:

```
pushd
import-module SQLPS
popd
```

That will restore the current directory after the module is imported.