# Search networked drive or UNC path

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell 5 to search a folder for the most recent .bak file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceBackupPath -Filter *.bak
```

This works fine if I pass in `"C:\temp\"` but if I pass in `"E:\temp\"`, I get the error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'E' does not exist.

If I pass in a UNC path `"\\MyServer\e$\Temp\"` I get the error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot call method. The provider does not support the use of filters.

Comment: In your second test, the one with the UNC reference, it should be "\\", not "\" -- was that just a typo?

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like stackoverflow converts 2 backslashes to 1.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceBackupPath | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.bak' }` then sort by date, then take the most recent, is the most direct way to do it. But depending on number of files and folders to search, Get-ChildItem can also be slowwwww and you'd want to dig out to command prompt 'dir', Robocopy, Windows search indexer, 'everything' api, etc. to list the files more quickly.

Comment: So -Filter doesn't work on networked drives or UNC paths?  That seems odd.  And what if I want to search for *\*sometext\*.bak*?

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceBackupPath | ? { $_.Name -like "*sometext*.bak" }  -- in this case, the asterisks are wildcards  or if you're good with regular expressions:  Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceBackupPath | ? { $_.Name -match 'somestring\.bak$' }

Comment: Curiously I cannot recreate the issue, I am able to get-childitem on any unc path with filters, No issues. `Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server01\Shared$\test" -Filter *.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQLPS by any chance?  If so, check your working directory by looking at the command prompt.  If it looks something like this:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

It means you you are issuing commands from the directory structure of the SQLPS provider, which doesn't recognize UNC paths by default.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50282266/6647010).